# How can an open area prevent its inhabitants from leaving?

Tags: magic, species, forestry

Long ago, the elven races were embroiled in a civil war called the sundering. This war split the elves into different groups, which eventually became separate races. The elves that remained in their original Homeland are referred to as the High Elves. The group that retreated underground were called the Dark elves. Finally, the last group retreated to the woods, and are derogatorily referred to as "The Elf Hippies".

This Forest is connected to every continent in the world, despite them being thousands of miles apart and separated by bodies of water. One can enter the forest from its entrance on their continent, and can exit in another. The forest is much bigger on the inside than it appears from the outside. It is here where the elf hippies formed their own society with the other forest spirits that inhabit the area. They spend their days being in tune with nature, taking hard drugs, and fornicating. They can also be violent towards other races that enter the forest, including other elves.

I want these elves to be isolated from their cousins so that they become an entirely different subspecies. While outsiders can enter and exit this Forest, the inhabitants that live within cannot exit. They are unable to leave the forest like others, despite the fact that there are no obstructions and is open to all. How can this be the case?

Comment: "They are unable to leave the forest like others, despite the fact that there are no obstructions and is open to all." So what you're saying is [they can check out any time they like, but they can never leave](https://youtu.be/iLNloNNXnbQ)?

Comment: This sounds like something you need to answer since it seems to be based on whatever magic allow the forest to bend space to connect to distant places. Since we don't know how your magic works we can't answer this for you.

Comment: Note that speciation will require tens of thousands of years, most likely longer to occur, this sundering will either have been a very long time ago, or, had magical implications that directly impact the problem at hand

Answer (score 20):

Extreme food specialization.

Think of panda with bamboo or koala with eucalyptus. There is nothing physically preventing a panda from leaving its bamboo forest, or a koala to venture outside the eucalyptus trees.

And indeed many other species freely roam in and out of those environments. The only thing is that if panda or koala leave, they are bound to quickly starve without a supply of food.

Comment: Replace "food" with "hard drugs not available in other countries" ;)

Comment: That might be an issue depending on how scientific you want to be about the issue. AFAIK, our omnivorous diet was a big factor in us evolving bigger brains and becoming as successful a species as we currently are. Would elves with (presumably) intelligence comparable to ours have evolved with such a limited variety of food?

Comment: @KaiGuyMBK Combined with the flavour-text in the question, I believe that the intent is for intelligence to develop *first*, and the food specialization develops **afterwards**.  Perhaps a type of fungus contains large amounts of free amino-acids, so the elves' bodies stop producing Protease with which to break down proteins in food?  (Like how some people stop producing lactase if they avoid milk for too long, becoming lactose intolerant.  Of course, still producing lactase after childhood is actually a mutation - most animals lose the ability as they grow up)

Comment: Still, a sentient species will manage it much better than animals. They can pack food for longer voyages, or they could even carry seeds with them to plant if they want to settle down elsewhere.

Comment: @vsz Good points, but depending on the characteristics of the food, there might still be an issue. It's possible that the particular food is only good fresh, and spoils or degrades within a day. It might also be particularly adapted to its native environment, making growing it elsewhere near impossible. Put these together, and you will never eat this food anywhere that's more than a day away from where it grows naturally.

Comment: @NuclearWang : indeed, that would make it much more difficult. But impossible? There are many ways to preserve food, few of which require the industrial revolution. Boiling it, cooking it, drying it, salting it, sealing it airtight under honey or grease or whatever.

Answer (score 15):

**How do they live *in* the forest?**

Before considering why they cannot live outside the forest, an important question is to determine how they can live at all.  The wood elves apparently:

> spend their days being in tune with nature, taking hard drugs, and fornicating

This is not a recipe for the continued existence of a primitive people, where all but the elite need to work the large majority of the time just to raise crops, gather and/or hunt food, prepare food, build shelters, raise children.  It is only in wealthy civilisations with excess food production that *anyone* can live this way, and they still need to be supported by productive workers.  Which means that the wood elves are being kept alive and provided with drugs deliberately by someone or something - forest spirits?

This has gone on, with the wood elves degenerating further and further as each generation of drug users gives birth to drug-addicted babies.  In the unlikely event that any wood elves wander away they suffer from drastic withdrawal symptoms very quickly and either return to their hard drug supplier or die.

Pretty dark, but it is hard to see how the lifestyle described could lead to any other outcome.

Comment: Interesting idea! You could take it one step further and say that woodland spirits or a woodland god of some sort has taken them captive and is keeping them hostage by drugging them and making them drown in hedonistic excess! Maybe the wood-elves are actually hypnotised by the woodland god so that they don't even realize they are being held captive and believe they are staying of their own free will, much like the Tau Empire uses pheromones in the 41st millenium?

Comment: @KaiGuyMBK I pared back my first draft a bit as I had started going past the "how" into the "why is some entity doing this to the elves?"    Does the violence towards intruders mean they are being used as a security force, are they pollinating plants as part of "being one with nature", is it some AI that has taken a particular interpretation of an instruction to "make everyone happy"?  Outside the scope of this forum though.

Comment: Besides the aforementioned drugs, there obviously must be *something* in the woods that they can *eat* and can obtain with minimal effort. IOW, this *plus* [L.Dutch](/users/30492)'s [answer](/a/174246/43697) / [Ville](/users/3434)'s [answer](/a/174266/43697). (Because while they may be *able* to eat outside food, they lack the work ethic to obtain it.)

Answer (score 7):

**Agoraphobia**

The elves have a fear of open spaces. They've lived so long in the trees that the thought of no trees scares them to the point they can't leave.

Answer (score 5):

### Magic Backfired

Toward the end of the Sundering after a particularly devastating turn, the proto-hippies used magic to shore up their strength, drawing on the longevity and other properties of the trees and woods. In doing so they bound themselves to it, perhaps accidentally or out of desperation, becoming entwined in and reliant on the world-wide [mycorrhizal network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycorrhizal_network#Importance_at_the_forest_community_level) linking the forests together.

Answer (score 2):

**Lack of easily accessible food.**

The forest elves are apparently hunter gatherers. They rely on the animals, fish and plants of the forest for food. Those animals and plants do not live outside the forest, so the forest elves leaving the forest would either starve or have to learn work hard like the pitiful outsiders that occasionally come to the forest to try steal some food.

Judging by the description of their current life style this is not a change they, apart from maybe few special individuals, would not be willing or even able to make. And why would they? Why would any sane person go from a place where food is easy to get and they can have as much free time as described to a place where food must be grown and hard work is required to avoid starvation?

And where would they even learn how to do any of that? Maybe someone who took lots of furs and "pretty stones" could sell those and buy food and accommodations with the money. But even they'd have to return before the money runs out. What else could they do? They have no family outside to help them and no applicable skills to earn a living.

They might be able to learn but working hard to learn skills needed to work hard is not only harder than you'd think, it is also pretty dumb when you have the option of simply going back home and living comfortably with skills you already have without any of that hard work.

Answer (score 2):

**Religion**:  This sounds religion/cultish. Perhaps the occasional individual wanders away, but the nature goddess/druidic cult says you are on the outs if you leave, and are shunned from the group. Look at the Amish - they live in an open contact with the outside, but are very separate. The Jews have maintained a separate cultural identity with even closer ties. Your wood elves are violently hostile to outsiders and have no/few resources to make it worth invading the woods. Add a demand that those on the inside of the faith aren't allowed to breed with those outside and you wouldn't need physical barriers.

Answer (score 2):

## They breathed a drug for generations it's now part of their body needs

Same mindset as Extreme food specialization.

**From the nature emanates the drug.**

Like you breath the drug all around you (coming from flowers on certain trees?).

That drug is not necessarily with negative effects or effects at all. It's a dependency.

So much drugs breathed that even babies are dependant on it at birth, or since they breath it they will be dependent really soon.

And there is a high mortality rate on those who try to stop/leave the forest so nobody risk it anymore; it could even be a death sentence in their laws. And since there is only one forest where there is this drug, there is only one place where they can stay.

If you need a winter scenario : You have to carve thoses flower trees to get the drug from the sap. Then they could possibly leave the forest, they just can't do it long enough without supply.

Answer (score 2):

Sunlight sensitivity.

Depending on how thick the forest is, and what types of trees you decide to place there, sections of the forest could be extremely dark places.  Over time, these elves may have adapted to the dark, causing extreme sensitivity to sunlight.  Long-term exposure to direct sunlight may result in blindness, severe sunburn (sun poisoning), inability to regulate internal temperature, etc; Possibly life threatening.

Individuals could travel at night, hope to find dark inns to spend their days in, and take various other precautions, but this would be rare.  Most of society would be content to stay in the environment that's well suited to them, the same way most of us don't live in Antarctica.

Answer (score 1):

**Must eat food "attuned" to the forest**
They cannot eat food that isn't in tune with the forest. So outside the forest they will eventually starve.

Maybe they can only get the food attuned to the forest from forest spirits, and if they are not in tune with the forest they will starve to death.

Maybe a darker version is that the food they get from the forest spirits contains a slow acting poison (or a drug) and a temporary antidote, so they have to keep eating the "attuned" food to avoid dying from the poison (or drug). Maybe the food also have benefits. This quickly makes it so a group of elves has to continue to stay in the forest and then becomes an isolated group. If all plants in the forest had this property it would also explain why others don't live in the forest, it's becuase they don't want to be stuck in the forest.

Answer (score 0):

**Magic.**

Specifically the same magic that creates this weird connected forrest in the first place. It prevents the hippie elves from leaving because it uses them to fuel the magic that keeps it all connected. Maybe they could even leave, but then the connected forrest would cease to exist, a thing every drug- and fornication-loving member of the hippie elves wants to prevent. Or for any other reason you want, it is magic after all!